# After integrating Infinispan 5.2.1 second level cache occurred org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: spring, hibernate, second-level-cache

I am using Infinispan L2 cache with Tomcat 6, Hibernate 4 Spring 3.5 and Junit 4.10. After integrating Infinispan cache I have encountered an exception when try to run application

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.connection.password' in string value "${hibernate.connection.password}": Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.connection.password' in string value "${hibernate.connection.password}"
```

All the hibernate.properties file and spring files are in relevant places where they were in previously.

My Infinspan configuration is

```
 <globalJmxStatistics enabled="true" jmxDomain="org.infinispan" allowDuplicateDomains="true"/>

<transport

        transportClass="org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport"

        clusterName="infinispan-hibernate-cluster"

        distributedSyncTimeout="50000"

        strictPeerToPeer="false">

    <properties>

        <property name="configurationFile" value="jgroups.xml"/>

    </properties>

</transport>

</global>
<default>

</default>



<namedCache name="my-cache-entity">

<clustering mode="replication">

    <stateRetrieval fetchInMemoryState="false" timeout="60000"/>

    <sync replTimeout="20000"/>

</clustering>

<locking isolationLevel="READ_COMMITTED" concurrencyLevel="1000"

         lockAcquisitionTimeout="15000" useLockStriping="false"/>

<eviction maxEntries="10000" strategy="LRU"/>

<expiration maxIdle="100000" wakeUpInterval="5000"/>

<lazyDeserialization enabled="true"/>

<!--<transaction useSynchronization="true"

             transactionMode="TRANSACTIONAL" autoCommit="false"

             lockingMode="OPTIMISTIC"/>-->

<loaders passivation="false" shared="false" preload="false">

    <loader class="org.infinispan.loaders.cluster.ClusterCacheLoader"

            fetchPersistentState="false"

            ignoreModifications="false" purgeOnStartup="false">

        <properties>

            <property name="remoteCallTimeout" value="20000"/>

        </properties>

    </loader>

</loaders>

</namedCache>
```

This is Spring configuration for the placeholders

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:tomcat-jdbc-pool.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:hibernate.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the config you added to configure Infinispan ?

Comment: I added configuration file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not clear : it's the Spring config you added that should have changed Spring's placeholder property loading. Can you please provide this config ?